# IF condition in trigger uses query

Tags: sql, triggers

> order_placed(order_no,mess_id,...) rates(mess_id,student_id,rating)

I want to create a trigger that checks if a mess's rating is less than 4 when an order is being placed, and if so, the order can't be placed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_order
AFTER INSERT ON order_placed
FOR EACH NEW ROW
BEGIN
IF((SELECT AVG(rating) FROM rates WHERE rates.mess_id = NEW.mess_id) < 4)
ROLLBACK TRAN
END;
```

I'm getting an `ERROR 1064`.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: It may be MySQL, as 1064 is "Syntax error".

Comment: We need the **full and exact** error message you are getting.